# MongoDB "Malformed geometry" when creating a geosphere index

Tags: python, mongodb

Using mongodb 2.6, pymongo 2.7 I try to create a 2dsphere index but it says the geometry is malformed:

```
source_db.region_test.drop()
source_db.region_test.insert({'geometry':
   {"type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 6.551007, 53.008742 ], [ 6.551085, 53.008695 ], [ 6.551112, 53.008702 ], [ 6.551141, 53.008707 ], [ 6.551171, 53.00871 ], [ 6.551201, 53.008709 ], [ 6.551231, 53.008706 ], [ 6.55126, 53.0087 ], [ 6.551356, 53.008676 ], [ 6.552235, 53.008457 ], [ 6.552391, 53.008418 ], [ 6.552391, 53.008417 ], [ 6.552864, 53.008299 ], [ 6.552959, 53.008275 ], [ 6.553397, 53.008166 ], [ 6.553422, 53.00816 ], [ 6.553454, 53.008151 ], [ 6.553474, 53.008148 ], [ 6.553494, 53.008147 ], [ 6.553514, 53.008149 ], [ 6.553534, 53.008152 ], [ 6.553552, 53.008157 ], [ 6.553569, 53.008164 ], [ 6.553583, 53.008172 ], [ 6.553595, 53.008182 ], [ 6.553607, 53.008198 ], [ 6.553652, 53.008185 ], [ 6.553646, 53.008177 ], [ 6.55364, 53.008168 ], [ 6.553637, 53.008159 ], [ 6.553636, 53.00815 ], [ 6.553638, 53.00814 ], [ 6.553642, 53.008131 ], [ 6.553649, 53.008122 ], [ 6.553658, 53.008115 ], [ 6.553669, 53.008108 ], [ 6.553681, 53.008102 ], [ 6.553695, 53.008097 ], [ 6.553737, 53.008087 ], [ 6.553736, 53.008086 ], [ 6.553703, 53.008037 ], [ 6.553703, 53.008036 ], [ 6.553694, 53.008038 ], [ 6.553675, 53.008041 ], [ 6.553655, 53.008041 ], [ 6.553636, 53.00804 ], [ 6.553617, 53.008036 ], [ 6.553602, 53.008032 ], [ 6.553589, 53.008027 ], [ 6.553577, 53.008021 ], [ 6.553567, 53.008015 ], [ 6.553559, 53.008007 ], [ 6.553557, 53.008008 ], [ 6.553551, 53.008001 ], [ 6.553545, 53.007993 ], [ 6.553455, 53.007858 ], [ 6.553421, 53.007811 ], [ 6.553412, 53.007797 ], [ 6.553393, 53.00777 ], [ 6.553379, 53.007748 ], [ 6.553292, 53.007621 ], [ 6.553288, 53.007616 ], [ 6.553207, 53.007496 ], [ 6.553201, 53.007487 ], [ 6.553067, 53.007296 ], [ 6.55303, 53.007244 ], [ 6.55296, 53.007152 ], [ 6.552886, 53.007061 ], [ 6.552885, 53.007059 ], [ 6.552883, 53.007057 ], [ 6.552801, 53.006961 ], [ 6.552715, 53.006866 ], [ 6.552713, 53.006864 ], [ 6.552676, 53.006825 ], [ 6.552663, 53.006811 ], [ 6.552608, 53.006758 ], [ 6.552588, 53.006738 ], [ 6.552587, 53.006736 ], [ 6.552473, 53.006627 ], [ 6.552465, 53.00662 ], [ 6.552455, 53.00661 ], [ 6.552445, 53.006601 ], [ 6.552291, 53.006463 ], [ 6.552278, 53.006452 ], [ 6.552276, 53.006451 ], [ 6.552273, 53.006448 ], [ 6.552182, 53.006367 ], [ 6.552128, 53.006325 ], [ 6.55207, 53.006282 ], [ 6.552051, 53.006269 ], [ 6.552047, 53.006266 ], [ 6.552044, 53.006264 ], [ 6.552042, 53.006261 ], [ 6.55204, 53.006258 ], [ 6.552036, 53.006244 ], [ 6.552036, 53.006229 ], [ 6.552039, 53.006215 ], [ 6.552046, 53.006202 ], [ 6.552056, 53.006189 ], [ 6.552069, 53.006177 ], [ 6.5521, 53.006155 ], [ 6.552112, 53.006146 ], [ 6.552131, 53.006133 ], [ 6.552188, 53.006093 ], [ 6.552068, 53.006031 ], [ 6.552044, 53.006018 ], [ 6.55198, 53.006049 ], [ 6.551955, 53.006058 ], [ 6.551929, 53.006065 ], [ 6.551901, 53.006069 ], [ 6.551872, 53.00607 ], [ 6.551843, 53.006068 ], [ 6.551839, 53.006067 ], [ 6.551836, 53.006067 ], [ 6.551833, 53.006065 ], [ 6.55183, 53.006064 ], [ 6.551742, 53.006005 ], [ 6.551688, 53.00597 ], [ 6.551498, 53.00585 ], [ 6.550895, 53.005495 ], [ 6.550916, 53.005475 ], [ 6.550888, 53.005464 ], [ 6.55087, 53.00548 ], [ 6.55005, 53.004997 ], [ 6.550028, 53.004982 ], [ 6.550008, 53.004966 ], [ 6.54998, 53.004942 ], [ 6.549949, 53.004921 ], [ 6.549775, 53.004819 ], [ 6.549744, 53.004804 ], [ 6.549711, 53.004791 ], [ 6.54968, 53.004778 ], [ 6.549652, 53.004763 ], [ 6.548993, 53.004376 ], [ 6.548926, 53.004336 ], [ 6.548899, 53.004321 ], [ 6.548873, 53.004304 ], [ 6.548851, 53.004284 ], [ 6.548833, 53.004264 ], [ 6.548812, 53.004237 ], [ 6.548787, 53.004211 ], [ 6.548774, 53.004198 ], [ 6.548733, 53.004164 ], [ 6.548698, 53.004139 ], [ 6.548658, 53.004117 ], [ 6.548638, 53.004104 ], [ 6.548595, 53.004065 ], [ 6.54856, 53.004023 ], [ 6.548534, 53.003979 ], [ 6.548533, 53.003976 ], [ 6.548532, 53.003972 ], [ 6.548533, 53.003968 ], [ 6.548543, 53.003941 ], [ 6.548548, 53.003919 ], [ 6.548549, 53.003897 ], [ 6.548536, 53.003857 ], [ 6.548517, 53.003818 ], [ 6.5485, 53.003779 ], [ 6.548487, 53.003741 ], [ 6.548478, 53.003695 ], [ 6.548478, 53.003649 ], [ 6.548486, 53.003598 ], [ 6.548501, 53.003548 ], [ 6.548512, 53.003515 ], [ 6.548515, 53.003508 ], [ 6.548508, 53.003508 ], [ 6.548502, 53.003509 ], [ 6.548496, 53.00351 ], [ 6.548488, 53.003512 ], [ 6.548481, 53.003516 ], [ 6.548475, 53.003519 ], [ 6.54847, 53.003524 ], [ 6.548467, 53.003529 ], [ 6.548465, 53.003534 ], [ 6.548461, 53.003547 ], [ 6.548482, 53.003422 ], [ 6.548482, 53.003429 ], [ 6.548484, 53.003436 ], [ 6.548488, 53.003442 ], [ 6.548494, 53.003447 ], [ 6.548502, 53.003452 ], [ 6.54851, 53.003457 ], [ 6.54852, 53.00346 ], [ 6.54853, 53.003462 ], [ 6.548541, 53.003463 ], [ 6.548546, 53.003448 ], [ 6.548863, 53.002459 ], [ 6.548839, 53.002456 ], [ 6.548794, 53.00245 ], [ 6.5488, 53.002435 ], [ 6.54881, 53.002418 ], [ 6.548839, 53.002372 ], [ 6.54888, 53.002304 ], [ 6.548879, 53.002305 ], [ 6.548876, 53.002314 ], [ 6.548876, 53.002318 ], [ 6.548877, 53.002321 ], [ 6.548878, 53.002325 ], [ 6.548933, 53.002324 ], [ 6.548963, 53.002323 ], [ 6.549066, 53.002089 ], [ 6.549091, 53.002033 ], [ 6.549123, 53.001961 ], [ 6.549125, 53.001956 ], [ 6.549177, 53.001839 ], [ 6.549259, 53.001653 ], [ 6.549261, 53.001642 ], [ 6.549264, 53.001636 ], [ 6.549238, 53.001635 ], [ 6.549214, 53.001634 ], [ 6.549206, 53.001634 ], [ 6.549199, 53.001635 ], [ 6.549192, 53.001637 ], [ 6.549185, 53.00164 ], [ 6.549179, 53.001644 ], [ 6.549173, 53.001648 ], [ 6.549169, 53.001653 ], [ 6.549165, 53.001658 ], [ 6.549216, 53.00155 ], [ 6.549215, 53.001555 ], [ 6.549216, 53.001559 ], [ 6.549218, 53.001564 ], [ 6.549221, 53.001568 ], [ 6.549226, 53.001572 ], [ 6.549231, 53.001575 ], [ 6.549238, 53.001578 ], [ 6.549245, 53.00158 ], [ 6.549252, 53.001581 ], [ 6.54926, 53.001582 ], [ 6.549262, 53.001582 ], [ 6.549289, 53.001583 ], [ 6.549292, 53.001577 ], [ 6.549298, 53.001567 ], [ 6.549349, 53.001466 ], [ 6.549496, 53.001173 ], [ 6.54955, 53.001076 ], [ 6.549691, 53.000821 ], [ 6.549801, 53.000654 ], [ 6.549836, 53.000602 ], [ 6.549908, 53.0005 ], [ 6.54992, 53.000484 ], [ 6.549995, 53.000385 ], [ 6.550203, 53.00014 ], [ 6.550215, 53.000125 ], [ 6.55021, 53.000124 ], [ 6.55019, 53.000117 ], [ 6.550177, 53.000112 ], [ 6.55017, 53.00011 ], [ 6.550162, 53.000109 ], [ 6.550154, 53.000109 ], [ 6.550146, 53.00011 ], [ 6.550138, 53.000111 ], [ 6.550131, 53.000113 ], [ 6.550125, 53.000116 ], [ 6.55012, 53.00012 ], [ 6.550116, 53.000124 ], [ 6.5502, 53.000025 ], [ 6.550197, 53.00003 ], [ 6.550195, 53.000035 ], [ 6.550195, 53.000039 ], [ 6.550196, 53.000044 ], [ 6.550198, 53.000049 ], [ 6.550202, 53.000053 ], [ 6.550206, 53.000057 ], [ 6.550212, 53.00006 ], [ 6.550219, 53.000063 ], [ 6.55023, 53.000067 ], [ 6.550254, 53.000077 ], [ 6.550327, 53.000008 ], [ 6.550519, 52.999852 ], [ 6.550536, 52.999836 ], [ 6.550651, 52.999709 ], [ 6.550687, 52.999701 ], [ 6.550725, 52.999696 ], [ 6.550763, 52.999694 ], [ 6.550802, 52.999696 ], [ 6.550965, 52.999714 ], [ 6.551116, 52.999732 ], [ 6.551144, 52.999737 ], [ 6.551171, 52.999745 ], [ 6.551239, 52.999767 ], [ 6.5513, 52.99979 ], [ 6.551317, 52.999774 ], [ 6.551333, 52.999758 ], [ 6.551415, 52.999679 ], [ 6.551433, 52.999662 ], [ 6.551449, 52.999647 ], [ 6.551213, 52.999553 ], [ 6.551206, 52.99955 ], [ 6.551199, 52.999546 ], [ 6.551194, 52.999541 ], [ 6.551095, 52.999447 ], [ 6.551084, 52.999438 ], [ 6.551076, 52.999428 ], [ 6.55107, 52.999417 ], [ 6.551068, 52.999406 ], [ 6.551068, 52.999395 ], [ 6.551071, 52.999383 ], [ 6.551077, 52.999373 ], [ 6.551086, 52.999363 ], [ 6.551098, 52.999354 ], [ 6.551181, 52.999293 ], [ 6.551307, 52.999201 ], [ 6.551378, 52.999155 ], [ 6.551455, 52.999112 ], [ 6.551572, 52.999053 ], [ 6.551816, 52.998932 ], [ 6.551818, 52.998931 ], [ 6.55182, 52.99893 ], [ 6.552088, 52.998802 ], [ 6.552299, 52.998703 ], [ 6.55231, 52.998698 ], [ 6.552316, 52.998694 ], [ 6.552341, 52.998708 ], [ 6.55236, 52.998696 ], [ 6.552417, 52.99866 ], [ 6.552418, 52.998659 ], [ 6.552418, 52.998658 ], [ 6.552418, 52.998658 ], [ 6.552418, 52.998657 ], [ 6.552418, 52.998656 ], [ 6.552417, 52.998655 ], [ 6.552417, 52.998655 ], [ 6.552416, 52.998654 ], [ 6.552394, 52.998642 ], [ 6.552335, 52.998617 ], [ 6.55233, 52.998615 ], [ 6.552323, 52.998614 ], [ 6.552317, 52.998613 ], [ 6.552311, 52.998612 ], [ 6.552266, 52.998614 ], [ 6.55226, 52.998615 ], [ 6.552254, 52.998616 ], [ 6.552248, 52.998618 ], [ 6.55244, 52.998528 ], [ 6.552437, 52.99853 ], [ 6.552435, 52.998532 ], [ 6.552434, 52.998534 ], [ 6.552425, 52.998573 ], [ 6.552425, 52.998575 ], [ 6.552425, 52.998576 ], [ 6.55243, 52.998587 ], [ 6.552437, 52.998597 ], [ 6.552447, 52.998607 ], [ 6.552458, 52.998615 ], [ 6.552465, 52.99862 ], [ 6.552469, 52.998622 ], [ 6.552476, 52.998617 ], [ 6.55249, 52.998611 ], [ 6.552849, 52.998443 ], [ 6.55291, 52.998416 ], [ 6.552972, 52.99839 ], [ 6.553036, 52.998365 ], [ 6.553087, 52.998347 ], [ 6.55314, 52.99833 ], [ 6.553244, 52.998296 ], [ 6.553297, 52.998279 ], [ 6.553348, 52.998259 ], [ 6.553377, 52.998248 ], [ 6.553389, 52.998243 ], [ 6.553423, 52.998228 ], [ 6.553378, 52.998192 ], [ 6.553377, 52.998191 ], [ 6.553376, 52.998191 ], [ 6.553375, 52.99819 ], [ 6.553351, 52.998186 ], [ 6.553326, 52.998184 ], [ 6.553304, 52.998184 ], [ 6.553282, 52.998186 ], [ 6.553198, 52.998203 ], [ 6.553605, 52.998022 ], [ 6.55357, 52.998068 ], [ 6.553565, 52.998077 ], [ 6.553562, 52.998087 ], [ 6.553561, 52.998096 ], [ 6.553562, 52.998106 ], [ 6.553594, 52.998145 ], [ 6.553599, 52.998156 ], [ 6.553609, 52.998169 ], [ 6.55362, 52.998182 ], [ 6.553624, 52.998183 ], [ 6.553628, 52.998184 ], [ 6.553632, 52.998185 ], [ 6.553651, 52.998187 ], [ 6.55367, 52.998187 ], [ 6.553629, 52.998136 ], [ 6.553757, 52.998077 ], [ 6.553792, 52.998098 ], [ 6.553824, 52.998079 ], [ 6.553876, 52.998047 ], [ 6.553952, 52.998001 ], [ 6.553925, 52.997985 ], [ 6.553994, 52.99794 ], [ 6.554026, 52.99792 ], [ 6.554076, 52.997891 ], [ 6.554133, 52.997858 ], [ 6.554212, 52.997817 ], [ 6.554293, 52.997777 ], [ 6.554451, 52.997704 ], [ 6.554577, 52.997644 ], [ 6.554685, 52.99759 ], [ 6.554793, 52.997536 ], [ 6.555155, 52.997347 ], [ 6.5552, 52.997322 ], [ 6.555242, 52.997294 ], [ 6.555321, 52.997239 ], [ 6.555341, 52.997225 ], [ 6.555361, 52.99721 ], [ 6.555362, 52.99721 ], [ 6.555374, 52.997212 ], [ 6.555381, 52.997211 ], [ 6.555389, 52.99721 ], [ 6.555397, 52.99721 ], [ 6.555405, 52.997211 ], [ 6.555412, 52.997213 ], [ 6.555419, 52.997215 ], [ 6.55546, 52.997235 ], [ 6.555475, 52.997243 ], [ 6.555492, 52.99723 ], [ 6.555484, 52.997226 ], [ 6.555429, 52.9972 ], [ 6.555419, 52.997197 ], [ 6.555408, 52.997195 ], [ 6.555397, 52.997194 ], [ 6.555386, 52.997194 ], [ 6.555375, 52.997195 ], [ 6.555367, 52.997196 ], [ 6.55536, 52.997198 ], [ 6.555404, 52.997179 ], [ 6.555466, 52.997152 ], [ 6.555531, 52.997122 ], [ 6.555521, 52.997127 ], [ 6.555512, 52.997134 ], [ 6.555506, 52.997141 ], [ 6.555503, 52.997147 ], [ 6.5555, 52.997152 ], [ 6.5555, 52.997158 ], [ 6.555501, 52.997161 ], [ 6.555503, 52.997168 ], [ 6.555508, 52.997175 ], [ 6.555514, 52.997181 ], [ 6.555521, 52.997187 ], [ 6.55553, 52.997192 ], [ 6.555537, 52.997196 ], [ 6.555535, 52.997198 ], [ 6.555569, 52.997215 ], [ 6.55557, 52.997214 ], [ 6.555591, 52.997199 ], [ 6.555605, 52.997189 ], [ 6.555612, 52.997185 ], [ 6.555587, 52.997169 ], [ 6.555576, 52.997174 ], [ 6.55556, 52.997163 ], [ 6.555543, 52.99716 ], [ 6.555543, 52.997158 ], [ 6.555544, 52.997155 ], [ 6.555545, 52.997152 ], [ 6.555547, 52.99715 ], [ 6.555549, 52.997147 ], [ 6.555583, 52.997127 ], [ 6.555595, 52.997129 ], [ 6.555637, 52.997105 ], [ 6.555664, 52.997106 ], [ 6.555679, 52.997096 ], [ 6.555678, 52.997086 ], [ 6.555691, 52.997079 ], [ 6.555729, 52.997078 ], [ 6.555755, 52.997063 ], [ 6.555777, 52.997076 ], [ 6.555785, 52.997081 ], [ 6.555813, 52.997082 ], [ 6.555837, 52.997098 ], [ 6.555848, 52.997092 ], [ 6.555853, 52.997089 ], [ 6.555855, 52.997088 ], [ 6.555879, 52.997075 ], [ 6.555865, 52.997066 ], [ 6.555842, 52.997056 ], [ 6.555817, 52.997048 ], [ 6.55579, 52.997043 ], [ 6.555761, 52.99704 ], [ 6.555732, 52.99704 ], [ 6.555702, 52.997043 ], [ 6.555675, 52.997049 ], [ 6.555649, 52.997058 ], [ 6.555625, 52.997068 ], [ 6.555604, 52.997054 ], [ 6.555609, 52.997051 ], [ 6.555685, 52.99701 ], [ 6.555645, 52.996983 ], [ 6.555646, 52.996982 ], [ 6.555646, 52.996982 ], [ 6.555647, 52.996981 ], [ 6.555647, 52.99698 ], [ 6.555647, 52.996979 ], [ 6.555647, 52.996978 ], [ 6.555646, 52.996978 ], [ 6.555646, 52.996977 ], [ 6.555645, 52.996976 ], [ 6.55564, 52.996973 ], [ 6.555639, 52.996973 ], [ 6.555638, 52.996972 ], [ 6.555636, 52.996972 ], [ 6.555635, 52.996972 ], [ 6.555634, 52.996972 ], [ 6.555633, 52.996972 ], [ 6.555631, 52.996973 ], [ 6.55563, 52.996973 ], [ 6.555567, 52.996932 ], [ 6.555614, 52.996905 ], [ 6.555653, 52.996883 ], [ 6.555654, 52.996882 ], [ 6.555655, 52.996882 ], [ 6.555655, 52.996881 ], [ 6.555656, 52.99688 ], [ 6.555656, 52.996879 ], [ 6.555655, 52.996879 ], [ 6.555655, 52.996878 ], [ 6.555654, 52.996877 ], [ 6.555654, 52.996876 ], [ 6.555653, 52.996876 ], [ 6.555651, 52.996875 ], [ 6.55565, 52.996875 ], [ 6.555649, 52.996875 ], [ 6.555648, 52.996875 ], [ 6.555646, 52.996875 ], [ 6.555645, 52.996875 ], [ 6.555644, 52.996876 ], [ 6.555643, 52.996876 ], [ 6.555479, 52.996969 ], [ 6.555455, 52.996954 ], [ 6.555475, 52.996939 ], [ 6.555491, 52.996922 ], [ 6.555502, 52.996904 ], [ 6.555509, 52.996886 ], [ 6.55551, 52.996866 ], [ 6.555506, 52.996847 ], [ 6.555498, 52.996833 ], [ 6.555486, 52.996819 ], [ 6.555472, 52.996806 ], [ 6.555462, 52.996799 ], [ 6.555435, 52.996812 ], [ 6.555416, 52.996821 ], [ 6.555395, 52.996807 ], [ 6.555386, 52.996812 ], [ 6.555249, 52.9967 ], [ 6.555118, 52.996586 ], [ 6.555003, 52.996477 ], [ 6.554875, 52.996345 ], [ 6.55475, 52.996211 ], [ 6.554694, 52.996151 ], [ 6.554566, 52.996014 ], [ 6.554442, 52.995885 ], [ 6.554378, 52.995814 ], [ 6.554335, 52.995771 ], [ 6.554289, 52.995731 ], [ 6.554164, 52.995629 ], [ 6.554099, 52.995616 ], [ 6.553586, 52.995057 ], [ 6.553584, 52.995056 ], [ 6.553597, 52.995036 ], [ 6.55292, 52.994296 ], [ 6.552911, 52.994286 ], [ 6.552931, 52.994279 ], [ 6.552926, 52.994273 ], [ 6.552918, 52.994276 ], [ 6.552907, 52.99428 ], [ 6.55288, 52.994251 ], [ 6.552871, 52.994132 ], [ 6.552878, 52.994132 ], [ 6.552878, 52.99413 ], [ 6.552869, 52.994131 ], [ 6.552868, 52.994123 ], [ 6.552875, 52.994123 ], [ 6.552871, 52.994075 ], [ 6.552866, 52.994075 ], [ 6.552861, 52.994075 ], [ 6.55275, 52.994079 ], [ 6.552749, 52.994073 ], [ 6.552735, 52.994073 ], [ 6.552736, 52.99408 ], [ 6.552679, 52.994082 ], [ 6.552673, 52.994082 ], [ 6.552672, 52.994074 ], [ 6.552545, 52.994033 ], [ 6.552442, 52.994037 ], [ 6.552434, 52.994037 ], [ 6.552433, 52.994035 ], [ 6.550627, 52.994096 ], [ 6.550627, 52.994094 ], [ 6.550625, 52.994091 ], [ 6.550558, 52.994093 ], [ 6.550551, 52.994021 ], [ 6.550619, 52.994019 ], [ 6.550627, 52.993976 ], [ 6.550628, 52.993972 ], [ 6.550628, 52.99397 ], [ 6.55062, 52.99397 ], [ 6.55062, 52.993963 ], [ 6.550597, 52.993963 ], [ 6.550596, 52.993959 ], [ 6.550566, 52.993909 ], [ 6.550567, 52.993905 ], [ 6.55056, 52.99388 ], [ 6.55056, 52.993876 ], [ 6.550558, 52.993876 ], [ 6.550555, 52.993875 ], [ 6.550553, 52.993875 ], [ 6.550551, 52.993874 ], [ 6.550534, 52.993866 ], [ 6.550532, 52.993865 ], [ 6.550531, 52.993863 ], [ 6.55053, 52.993862 ], [ 6.550529, 52.993861 ], [ 6.550528, 52.99386 ], [ 6.550528, 52.993859 ], [ 6.550529, 52.993858 ], [ 6.550529, 52.993857 ], [ 6.550529, 52.993857 ], [ 6.55053, 52.993856 ], [ 6.550531, 52.993856 ], [ 6.550532, 52.993855 ], [ 6.550533, 52.993855 ], [ 6.550534, 52.993855 ], [ 6.550535, 52.993855 ], [ 6.550535, 52.993853 ], [ 6.550172, 52.993866 ], [ 6.550128, 52.993868 ], [ 6.549952, 52.993874 ], [ 6.54977, 52.99388 ], [ 6.549712, 52.993882 ], [ 6.549632, 52.993884 ], [ 6.549561, 52.993886 ], [ 6.548886, 52.993906 ], [ 6.548799, 52.993908 ], [ 6.548622, 52.993913 ], [ 6.548534, 52.993916 ], [ 6.548512, 52.993916 ], [ 6.548395, 52.993919 ], [ 6.54837, 52.99392 ], [ 6.548261, 52.993922 ], [ 6.548089, 52.993927 ], [ 6.548021, 52.993929 ], [ 6.547898, 52.993932 ], [ 6.547829, 52.993933 ], [ 6.547748, 52.993935 ], [ 6.547656, 52.993937 ], [ 6.54757, 52.993939 ], [ 6.547488, 52.993941 ], [ 6.547413, 52.993942 ], [ 6.547298, 52.993945 ], [ 6.547236, 52.993947 ], [ 6.547153, 52.99395 ], [ 6.547066, 52.993952 ], [ 6.546988, 52.993955 ], [ 6.546649, 52.993967 ], [ 6.546526, 52.993971 ], [ 6.546446, 52.993974 ], [ 6.546328, 52.993977 ], [ 6.546242, 52.99398 ], [ 6.546181, 52.993982 ], [ 6.545887, 52.993992 ], [ 6.545875, 52.993995 ], [ 6.545783, 52.993999 ], [ 6.545766, 52.993996 ], [ 6.545757, 52.993996 ], [ 6.545653, 52.994 ], [ 6.544728, 52.994032 ], [ 6.543063, 52.994087 ], [ 6.542921, 52.994092 ], [ 6.541735, 52.994132 ], [ 6.540374, 52.994177 ], [ 6.538604, 52.994237 ], [ 6.538533, 52.994239 ], [ 6.538428, 52.994243 ], [ 6.538348, 52.994245 ], [ 6.538289, 52.994246 ], [ 6.538218, 52.994245 ], [ 6.538102, 52.994241 ], [ 6.538035, 52.99424 ], [ 6.537943, 52.99424 ], [ 6.537866, 52.994243 ], [ 6.537375, 52.994256 ], [ 6.536795, 52.994271 ], [ 6.536717, 52.994273 ], [ 6.53604, 52.994291 ], [ 6.53604, 52.994292 ], [ 6.536027, 52.994292 ], [ 6.53602, 52.994292 ], [ 6.536012, 52.994291 ], [ 6.536005, 52.99429 ], [ 6.535774, 52.994212 ], [ 6.535766, 52.99421 ], [ 6.535758, 52.994209 ], [ 6.535749, 52.994209 ], [ 6.535624, 52.994216 ], [ 6.53564, 52.994243 ], [ 6.535655, 52.994259 ], [ 6.535674, 52.994273 ], [ 6.535696, 52.994286 ], [ 6.53572, 52.994297 ], [ 6.535748, 52.994305 ], [ 6.535776, 52.994311 ], [ 6.535776, 52.994316 ], [ 6.535776, 52.994322 ], [ 6.535875, 52.994401 ], [ 6.535875, 52.994407 ], [ 6.536301, 52.994392 ], [ 6.536311, 52.994475 ], [ 6.536321, 52.994515 ], [ 6.536342, 52.994554 ], [ 6.536362, 52.994579 ], [ 6.536379, 52.994603 ], [ 6.53639, 52.994628 ], [ 6.536396, 52.994653 ], [ 6.53642, 52.99485 ], [ 6.536425, 52.994891 ], [ 6.536427, 52.994946 ], [ 6.536419, 52.994995 ], [ 6.536402, 52.995044 ], [ 6.536374, 52.995095 ], [ 6.53634, 52.995145 ], [ 6.536299, 52.995193 ], [ 6.536254, 52.995237 ], [ 6.536217, 52.995267 ], [ 6.536183, 52.995291 ], [ 6.536084, 52.995353 ], [ 6.536083, 52.995355 ], [ 6.535943, 52.995442 ], [ 6.535901, 52.995416 ], [ 6.535875, 52.995432 ], [ 6.535802, 52.99539 ], [ 6.535693, 52.995327 ], [ 6.535619, 52.995286 ], [ 6.535547, 52.995246 ], [ 6.535466, 52.995194 ], [ 6.53537, 52.995135 ], [ 6.535235, 52.995049 ], [ 6.53513, 52.995105 ], [ 6.535065, 52.99514 ], [ 6.534956, 52.995199 ], [ 6.534646, 52.995391 ], [ 6.534722, 52.995437 ], [ 6.534845, 52.995508 ], [ 6.534943, 52.995565 ], [ 6.53497, 52.995582 ], [ 6.534836, 52.995664 ], [ 6.534702, 52.995585 ], [ 6.534648, 52.995617 ], [ 6.534568, 52.995665 ], [ 6.534516, 52.995696 ], [ 6.534271, 52.995552 ], [ 6.534112, 52.995649 ], [ 6.534072, 52.995674 ], [ 6.533957, 52.995744 ], [ 6.533668, 52.995574 ], [ 6.533379, 52.995405 ], [ 6.533108, 52.995572 ], [ 6.533028, 52.995621 ], [ 6.532939, 52.995676 ], [ 6.532719, 52.995812 ], [ 6.532709, 52.995819 ], [ 6.532741, 52.995837 ], [ 6.533111, 52.996055 ], [ 6.533173, 52.996091 ], [ 6.53349, 52.996273 ], [ 6.53325, 52.996426 ], [ 6.533281, 52.996443 ], [ 6.533101, 52.996555 ], [ 6.532952, 52.996648 ], [ 6.532803, 52.996561 ], [ 6.532768, 52.996584 ], [ 6.532552, 52.996722 ], [ 6.532506, 52.996751 ], [ 6.532361, 52.996844 ], [ 6.532254, 52.996912 ], [ 6.532147, 52.996978 ], [ 6.532062, 52.997032 ], [ 6.531997, 52.997074 ], [ 6.531886, 52.997145 ], [ 6.531958, 52.997214 ], [ 6.532022, 52.997267 ], [ 6.532092, 52.997322 ], [ 6.532158, 52.997371 ], [ 6.532223, 52.997414 ], [ 6.532475, 52.997582 ], [ 6.532425, 52.997612 ], [ 6.532386, 52.99759 ], [ 6.532386, 52.99759 ], [ 6.532383, 52.997594 ], [ 6.532352, 52.997613 ], [ 6.532351, 52.997614 ], [ 6.532391, 52.997636 ], [ 6.532404, 52.997646 ], [ 6.532414, 52.997656 ], [ 6.532423, 52.997667 ], [ 6.532429, 52.997679 ], [ 6.532432, 52.997692 ], [ 6.532432, 52.997705 ], [ 6.532427, 52.997717 ], [ 6.532419, 52.99773 ], [ 6.532408, 52.997741 ], [ 6.532446, 52.997763 ], [ 6.532511, 52.997722 ], [ 6.532512, 52.997721 ], [ 6.532513, 52.997721 ], [ 6.532513, 52.997721 ], [ 6.532514, 52.997721 ], [ 6.532515, 52.997721 ], [ 6.532516, 52.997721 ], [ 6.532517, 52.997721 ], [ 6.532519, 52.997721 ], [ 6.53252, 52.997721 ], [ 6.53252, 52.997722 ], [ 6.532535, 52.997731 ], [ 6.532536, 52.997731 ], [ 6.53254, 52.997734 ], [ 6.532539, 52.997734 ], [ 6.532673, 52.997813 ], [ 6.532671, 52.997814 ], [ 6.532686, 52.997823 ], [ 6.532688, 52.997822 ], [ 6.532731, 52.997848 ], [ 6.532733, 52.997846 ], [ 6.532737, 52.997849 ], [ 6.53274, 52.99785 ], [ 6.532729, 52.997857 ], [ 6.532727, 52.997857 ], [ 6.532553, 52.997968 ], [ 6.532578, 52.997983 ], [ 6.532613, 52.998006 ], [ 6.532637, 52.998021 ], [ 6.53271, 52.998067 ], [ 6.532686, 52.998082 ], [ 6.53271, 52.998095 ], [ 6.532705, 52.998098 ], [ 6.532722, 52.998109 ], [ 6.532823, 52.998169 ], [ 6.533112, 52.998339 ], [ 6.534389, 52.99909 ], [ 6.537971, 53.001195 ], [ 6.538115, 53.001279 ], [ 6.538182, 53.001315 ], [ 6.538338, 53.001392 ], [ 6.53853, 53.001486 ], [ 6.538736, 53.001588 ], [ 6.538915, 53.001675 ], [ 6.538964, 53.001699 ], [ 6.538979, 53.001706 ], [ 6.538998, 53.001718 ], [ 6.539239, 53.001859 ], [ 6.539435, 53.001973 ], [ 6.539432, 53.001975 ], [ 6.539616, 53.002083 ], [ 6.539627, 53.002089 ], [ 6.539648, 53.002101 ], [ 6.539653, 53.002103 ], [ 6.539684, 53.002115 ], [ 6.539718, 53.002123 ], [ 6.539754, 53.002128 ], [ 6.539791, 53.002129 ], [ 6.539828, 53.002126 ], [ 6.539863, 53.002119 ], [ 6.539896, 53.002109 ], [ 6.539926, 53.002096 ], [ 6.539973, 53.002123 ], [ 6.539849, 53.002199 ], [ 6.539847, 53.002201 ], [ 6.539846, 53.002202 ], [ 6.539845, 53.002204 ], [ 6.539845, 53.002205 ], [ 6.539845, 53.002207 ], [ 6.539845, 53.002208 ], [ 6.539846, 53.00221 ], [ 6.539847, 53.002211 ], [ 6.539849, 53.002213 ], [ 6.539851, 53.002214 ], [ 6.539853, 53.002214 ], [ 6.539856, 53.002215 ], [ 6.539859, 53.002215 ], [ 6.539861, 53.002215 ], [ 6.539864, 53.002215 ], [ 6.539866, 53.002215 ], [ 6.539869, 53.002214 ], [ 6.539871, 53.002213 ], [ 6.539886, 53.002204 ], [ 6.539996, 53.002137 ], [ 6.540069, 53.00218 ], [ 6.540009, 53.002217 ], [ 6.539987, 53.002235 ], [ 6.53997, 53.002254 ], [ 6.539958, 53.002275 ], [ 6.539953, 53.002297 ], [ 6.539953, 53.002319 ], [ 6.539959, 53.002341 ], [ 6.539971, 53.002362 ], [ 6.539989, 53.002381 ], [ 6.540012, 53.002398 ], [ 6.540045, 53.002419 ], [ 6.540049, 53.002417 ], [ 6.540923, 53.002932 ], [ 6.54098, 53.002966 ], [ 6.541043, 53.003005 ], [ 6.541118, 53.003055 ], [ 6.541229, 53.003131 ], [ 6.542041, 53.003701 ], [ 6.54227, 53.003862 ], [ 6.542324, 53.003898 ], [ 6.54238, 53.003934 ], [ 6.54249, 53.004004 ], [ 6.542607, 53.004074 ], [ 6.542603, 53.004077 ], [ 6.542843, 53.004217 ], [ 6.543605, 53.004665 ], [ 6.544748, 53.005337 ], [ 6.545724, 53.005911 ], [ 6.545776, 53.005942 ], [ 6.545937, 53.006036 ], [ 6.546672, 53.006468 ], [ 6.547075, 53.006706 ], [ 6.547275, 53.00683 ], [ 6.547377, 53.006893 ], [ 6.547546, 53.007 ], [ 6.547692, 53.007088 ], [ 6.547747, 53.007122 ], [ 6.547809, 53.007161 ], [ 6.547865, 53.007201 ], [ 6.547913, 53.007239 ], [ 6.547966, 53.007284 ], [ 6.54802, 53.007331 ], [ 6.548066, 53.007371 ], [ 6.548117, 53.007415 ], [ 6.548166, 53.00746 ], [ 6.548316, 53.007596 ], [ 6.548499, 53.007763 ], [ 6.548521, 53.007785 ], [ 6.548532, 53.007793 ], [ 6.548581, 53.007823 ], [ 6.548582, 53.007824 ], [ 6.548604, 53.007834 ], [ 6.548628, 53.007843 ], [ 6.54867, 53.007853 ], [ 6.548714, 53.007859 ], [ 6.548759, 53.00786 ], [ 6.548803, 53.007857 ], [ 6.548847, 53.00785 ], [ 6.548888, 53.007839 ], [ 6.548959, 53.007817 ], [ 6.549077, 53.007921 ], [ 6.549025, 53.007941 ], [ 6.548982, 53.007957 ], [ 6.548945, 53.007977 ], [ 6.548912, 53.008 ], [ 6.548887, 53.008026 ], [ 6.548868, 53.008054 ], [ 6.548857, 53.008083 ], [ 6.548853, 53.008115 ], [ 6.548862, 53.008145 ], [ 6.548878, 53.008173 ], [ 6.548902, 53.0082 ], [ 6.549002, 53.008241 ], [ 6.549025, 53.008263 ], [ 6.549171, 53.008399 ], [ 6.54919, 53.008417 ], [ 6.549314, 53.008531 ], [ 6.549329, 53.008595 ], [ 6.549754, 53.008992 ], [ 6.549771, 53.009016 ], [ 6.549821, 53.009062 ], [ 6.550117, 53.009339 ], [ 6.55036, 53.009244 ], [ 6.550524, 53.009147 ], [ 6.550707, 53.009038 ], [ 6.5507, 53.009033 ], [ 6.551066, 53.008816 ], [ 6.551044, 53.008797 ], [ 6.551009, 53.008767 ], [ 6.551009, 53.008751 ], [ 6.551001, 53.008746 ], [ 6.551007, 53.008742 ] ] ] ] }
})
source_db.region_test.ensure_index([('geometry', pymongo.GEOSPHERE)])
```

however, when I use geojsonlint it states that it's fine and originally it comes from PostGis which thought it was fine too. It closes the polygon nice also...
Any idea what might be the reason for mongodb to freak out here?

Edit: based on Helmy's suggestion I posted it as an issue: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13735

Comment: That looks like a bug to me, the MultiPolygon is valid according to GeoJSONLint.

Comment: I wonder if this might be the same issue as [SERVER-9240](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9240)

Comment: Thanks Helmy, so i might have to check the polygon for recurring points? Strange though as theoretically you can have polygon returning to the same point (drawing it without such n intermediate point would give it a rather different look)

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think is a different bug and you should report it. I tested with nightly and it still breaks there.

Comment: Recurring points other than the first/last point are: 6.552417, 52.998655
6.552418, 52.998658
6.555646, 52.996982 Removing them does not appear to help.

Comment: Thanks helmy; I will post it as a bug